# Permissions of / (root) directory are not correct

Tags: linux, centos, sftp

I've been struggling with my CentOS server for a while now, trying to add an account for (S)FTP access. I use sshd (OpenSSH) to connect to the ftp and with the root user everything is working just fine. When adding an account i can't access it with the SU command or FTP client. I've done a lot of research and i think the problem might have to do with the fact that my / folder has the wrong permissions.
When running `ls -id /` it outputs `64 /`
(The / is blue)

I've heard it should be 755 but i don't know how to do this and i don't know if this will fix the entire problem.

To wrap things up,
I need an SFTP account with access to a single directory and it's subfolders and no SSH but i can't even get it working as a normal user.

Thanks in advance,
Martijn Oosterhuis

Comment: Note that `sftp` and `ftp` are very different: `sftp` is just `ssh` with an ftp-like client, but using `sshd`; `ftp` uses its own `ftpd` demon. So to fix your `sftp` problem, look at `sshd_config`, usually in `/etc/ssh/` (no idea for CentOS). See `man sshd_config`.

Answer (score 1):

`-i` prints the inode number of the entry, not its permissions. `-l` will output the permissions along with other information about the entry.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x. 18 root root 276 26 okt 13:57 /
is the output of ls -ld /

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x root root` for `/` is correct, so whatever your (Martijn's) problem is, it's something else.